# FIX IT INFORMATICA Error TT_11019 There is an error in the port [port_name]:

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

"My Mapping is going down with the error message code :TT_11019" and the Mapping logic is as stated below

#

```
Source1(DB2)------>   SOURCE QUALIFIER--->Expression_Trsnfm->TGT_Flat_file
Source2(DB2)------>
```

As of Now I have verified the source data

STEP1: DATA looks good from the two DB2 SOURCES

STEP2:  Found that The data from Source qualifier to Expression 
          transformation populating NULL records **DO know HOW Till the source 
          qualifier data looks perfect**

STEP3: Research on session properties looks GOOD I HOPE

```
    Severity    Timestamp   Node    Thread  Message Code Message     

    ERROR   10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    TRANSF_1_1_1     
    TT_11019    There is an error in the port [EMP_ID]: The default 
    value for the port is set to: ERROR(Transformation error: 
    exp_INSTANCE).
    ERROR   10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    TRANSF_1_1_1     
    TT_11023    An error occurred converting data in the port 
    [EMP_ID]. The row was dropped.
    ERROR   10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    TRANSF_1_1_1     
    TT_11021    An error occurred moving data from the transformation 
    exp_INSTANCE: to the transformation EX655_KEY_FILE.
    ERROR   10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    TRANSF_1_1_1     
    CMN_1086    exp_INSTANCE: Number of errors exceeded threshold [1].
    INFO    10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    TRANSF_1_1_1     
    CMN_1053    : Rowdata: ( RowType=-4(error but dropped due to 
    abort) Src Rowid=3 Targ Rowid=3
     EMP_ID (EMP_ID:Int:): "(NULL)"
     MANGER_ID (MANAGER_ID:UniChar.17:): "20190917174013514"
     DEPT_ID (DEPT_ID:Int:): "(NULL)"
     OUT_XYZ_ID (XYZ_ID:UniChar.44:): "  "
     OUT_MU_PARTY_BUSN_ID (MU_PARTY_BUSN_ID:Int:): "0"
     BUSN_ID (BUSN_ID:Int:): "2435126"
     OUT_MOBILE_NUM (MOBILE_NUM:UniChar.30:): "  "
     OUT_STATE_CD (STATE_CD:UniChar.6:): "  "
     HIRE_DT (HIRE_DT:UniChar.10:): "(NULL)"
     OUT_DIST_TYP_CD (DIST_TYP_CD:UniChar.1:): " (TRUNCATED)"
     STATE_NO (STATE_NO:UniChar.2:): "16"
     STATUS_ID (QUOTE_APP_STATUS_ID:UniChar.2:): "CQ"
     SECTOR_TYP_CD(APP_TYPE_CD:UniChar.1:): "N"
     VACANCY_IND (PLCY_INQ_QUOTE_IND:UniChar.1:): "U"
     OUT_JOIN_DT (JOIN_DT:UniChar.10:): "01/01/0001(TRUNCATED)"
     OUT_EFF_DT (EFF_DT:UniChar.10:): "(NULL)"
     REGION_ID(REGION_ID:Int:): "2430919"
     )

    ERROR   10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    TRANSF_1_1_1     
    TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation [exp_INSTANCE], and 
    the session is terminating. 
    ERROR   10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    TRANSF_1_1_1     
    TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation 
    [SQ_DB2SRC1_DB2SRC2], and the session is terminating. 
    ERROR   10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    TRANSF_1_1_1     
    TM_6085 A fatal error occurred at  transformation 
    [SQ_DB2SRC1_DB2SRC2], and the session is terminating. 
    INFO    10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    WRITER_1_*_1     
    WRT_8333    Rolling back all the targets due to fatal session 
    error.
    ERROR   10/21/2019 9:37:05 PM   car_nod_exyz124i    WRT_8170     
    Writer run terminated: Abort Session request received from the DTM*
```

"I would like to resolve this issue and want to know the root cause"

Answer (score 0):

Is your port EMP_ID a NOT NULL field? If so, it seems you are trying to load a NULL value in it.